# I need to compare two classes in an if statement

Tags: jquery

So I have a website with a couple of images, and this is what I want it to do...

If somebody clicks a button with the class `lol`, **and the picture currently being shown has a class name with the same value** - do something.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="lol">BUTTON</div>
<div class="whatever">
<img src="x" class="lol"/ >
</div>
```

I've styled `div.lol` and `img.lol` in my CSS.

This is what I thought the jQuery would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.lol').click(function(){
        if($(this)===$('img.lol')){
            alert("LOL");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you determine what image is currently being shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
if ($(this).hasClass("lol"))
```

Comment: He is binding click event to element `div.lol` and inside the handler doing a `$(this).hasClass("lol")` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign an ID to the image that you want to check, and then use hasClass on that image. The code below worked for me:

```
<div class="lol">BUTTON</div>
<div class="whatever">
<img id = "an_image" src="x" class="lol"/ >
</div>
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.lol').click(function(){
        if($("#an_image").hasClass("lol")){
            alert("LOL");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> and the picture currently being shown has a class name with the same
>   value

I'm guessing you want to check a visible image for the class `.lol`, and the below will do that, but it will target all visible images, you probably need to limit that to some containing element etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.lol').click(function(){
        if ($('img:visible').is('.lol')) {
            alert("LOL");
        }
    });
});
```